# Como saber si existe un elemento dentro de un arreglo

Tags: php, array

estoy utilizando laravel y realice la siguiente consulta:

```
$soluciones = DB::table('soluciones')
                            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as Hours'), DB::raw('MONTH(soluciones.fecha_inc) AS period'))
                            ->where('soluciones.user_id', '=', '1')
                            ->groupBy('period')
                            ->orderBy('period', 'desc')
                            ->get();
```

Esta consulta funciona perfectamente y me manda a la vista el siguiente arreglo:
​

```
0: Object { Hours: 2, period: 7 }
​
1: Object { Hours: 3, period: 6 }
​
length: 2
```

Ahora bien me cree el siguiente arreglo: `$a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);` y el objetivo es recorrer el arreglo `$soluciones` de la consulta que realice, buscando si existe un `period` que coincida con algún número del arreglo `$a`

Esto es lo que he realizado pero no me funciona y en el arreglo obtenido se que hay `period` con valores numéricos que se encuentran en el arreglo `$a`:

```
foreach($a as $b){
        if (array_key_exists($b, $soluciones)) {
            echo 'existe';
        } else {
            echo 'no existe';
        }
    }
```

Por qué me sucede esto colegas?
​

Comment: Igual un `whereIn()` directo en la consulta ayudarría :https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Tendrias que utilizar el in_array para verificar si esta el objeto en el array

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría sería recorrer el `array` de objetos que tienes para ir preguntando con la función `in_array` si el valor de `period` se encuentra dentro del `array` de valores `$a`

```
$a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$array = [
    (object) [
    'hours' => 2,
    'period' => 15,
  ],
    (object) [
    'hours' => 3,
    'period' => 6,
  ]
];

foreach($array as $objeto) {
    if (in_array($objeto->period, $a)) {
        echo 'El valor ' . $objeto->period . ' existe en el array<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'El valor ' . $objeto->period . ' NO existe en el array<br>';
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
El valor 15 NO existe en el array
El valor 6 existe en el array
```

**Referencia:** [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

Comment: por curiosidad.. en la consulta no puede hacer un `IN`?

Comment: Por poder podría, pero a lo mejor le es más cómodo tener el "filtro" en el **PHP** en vez de en la consulta. O a lo mejor quiere tener ese `array` sin filtrar por esos valores porque lo quiere luego usar en otro lado sin ese filtro. Sin ver el contexto es difícil saber que vendría mejor usar ^^

Comment: ya tu sabes la respuesta.. de que es lo mejor dejar usar xD

Comment: y si no se encuentra como puedo adicionar en un arreglo el elemento que no esta, asi de esta forma. sldos
$ab = [
                    'Hours' => 0,
                    'period' => convertirFechaMes($b)
                ];

                $arr [] = $ab;

Comment: si mi arreglo $a fuera de esta forma $a = Array('period' => 1, 'period' => 2, 'period' => 3, 'period' => 4, 'period' => 5, 'period' => 6, 'period' => 7, 'period' => 8,
            'period' => 9, 'period' => 10, 'period' => 11, 'period' => 12); como pudiera usar el in_array recorriendo el arreglo $a. sldos

Comment: No puedes tener un `array` asociativo con la misma clave repetida en varios elementos. Lo que estás provocando con esa declaración de tu array `$a` es sobreescribir la clave *period* de tal manera que al final te quedará un array  solamente de un elemento: `array(1) { ["period"]=> int(12) }`