# Como saber si existe un elemento dentro de un arreglo con la estructura Array('period' => 1, 'period' => 2)

Tags: php, array

Esta pregunta me la he formulado en par de ocasiones, inclusive en una ocasión la realice y se aclaro, pero se me genero otra duda y la expongo.

Utilizando laravel realice la siguiente consulta:

```
$soluciones = DB::table('soluciones')
                            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as Hours'), DB::raw('MONTH(soluciones.fecha_inc) AS period'))
                            ->where('soluciones.user_id', '=', '1')
                            ->groupBy('period')
                            ->orderBy('period', 'desc')
                            ->get();
```

Ésta consulta funciona perfectamente y me manda a la vista el siguiente arreglo: ​

```
0: Object { Hours: 2, period: 7 }
​
1: Object { Hours: 3, period: 6 }
​
length: 2
```

A esta interrogante cortésmente aportaron el siguiente código que le daba solución:

```
$a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$array = [
    (object) [
    'hours' => 2,
    'period' => 15,
  ],
    (object) [
    'hours' => 3,
    'period' => 6,
  ]
];

foreach($array as $objeto) {
    if (in_array($objeto->period, $a)) {
        echo 'El valor ' . $objeto->period . ' existe en el array<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'El valor ' . $objeto->period . ' NO existe en el array<br>';
    }
}
```

Pero mi interés es no recorrer el arreglo `$array` como muestra la solución sino recorrer el arreglo `$a`

Lo intento hacer de esta forma:

```
foreach($a as $b){
        if (in_array($b, $soluciones)) {
            foreach($soluciones as $solucion){
                if($solucion->period == $b){
                    $ab = [
                        'Hours' => $solucion->Hours,
                        'period' => convertirFechaMes($solucion->period)
                    ];

                    $arr [] = $ab;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $ab = [
                'Hours' => 0,
                'period' => convertirFechaMes($b)
            ];

            $arr [] = $ab;
        }
    }
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

¿Como puedo hacer el *in_array* pero usando como *haystack* el arreglo soluciones? ​

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como saber si existe un elemento dentro de un arreglo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371672/como-saber-si-existe-un-elemento-dentro-de-un-arreglo)

Comment: no lo responde, porque estoy intentando hacer el proceso recorriendo el arreglo $a y no el arreglo soluciones,

Comment: enseguida edito la pregunta

Comment: es que en esa acertada respuesta estan recorriendo el arreglo soluciones y solo me devuelve los dos elementos period que encuentra en el arreglo $a. Pero en realidad quiero que me devuelva todos los que estan y los que no estan con la estructura { Hours: 2, period: 7 }

Comment: Lo que me pregunto es, ¿si tus datos vienen de una base de datos, por qué no te replanteas la consulta, de modo que obtengas los datos que quieres y como los quieres sin tener que estar mareando tanto los resultados? Generalmente los datos se organizan en BD relacionales para luego, en base a esas relaciones, poder obtener ciertos conjuntos de datos agrupados y/o ordenados según determinados contextos. Creo que aquí una solución más óptima sería refinar tu consulta, para que te de los datos que quieres sin dar tantas vueltas.